# How to pass a batch file argument with a dot character in it?

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I have a batch file that accepts part of the database name as an argument and create the database. Part of the batch file is like the following:

eg.

```
sqlcmd -S %1 -i "createDB.sql" -v dbname = DB%2
```

the second parameter is supposed to be a version which could have a dot in it, like 15.3, or 14.0.60 but when I pass this version number it doesn't create the DB and raise an error but if I pass just a simple number like 23, 10 it works.

Would you please help me what the problem is?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For future reference, "raises an error" without any information about what the error is is not useful. You need to provide specific information about the error, including the *exact* error message text. This helps people help you more quickly, which is good for both you and those who are trying to assist you. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Fisseha Please post the exact error message you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try wrapping it in quotes? I think that's the correct specification for `sqlcmd -v`.

ie.

```
sqlcmd -S %1 -i "createDB.sql" -v dbname = "DB%2"
```

Comment: Still complaining incorrect syntax for the argument, the argument I pass is like servername\instance 16.30   and its saying incorrect syntax near .30

Comment: You need to post the exact error message you are receiving if you want more help.

Answer (score 0):

I should add quotation marks to variable value. It will work

```
sqlcmd -S %1 -i "createDB.sql" -v dbname = "DB%2"
```

Comment: Still complaining incorrect syntax for the argument, the argument I pass is like servername\instance 16.30 and its saying incorrect syntax near .30

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the question is not about how to pass the dot character as part of an argument of a batch file, but rather about how to quote the identifier that contains a dot character properly *in SQL*, and more specifically, it seems, in Transact-SQL.

I think you should try additionally to enclose the name of the database in square brackets, like this:

```
sqlcmd -S %1 -i "createDB.sql" -v dbname = "[DB%2]"
```

Alternatively you might need to include the brackets around `$dbname` in the SQL script (i.e. *instead* of putting them on the command line), but without seeing that script I cannot say for sure.